# php laravel consulta de datos relacionados

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy queriendo que estire de la tabla Client el "email" pero me esta pasando el id del cliente.
Si me pudieran dar una mano para guiarme de como puedo hacer el pedido.

para realizar el pedido estoy usando belongsTo.

Client.php

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone',
        
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function appointments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Appointment::class);
    }
}
```

Appointment.php

```
class Appointment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'dated_at',
        'finish_at',
        'duration',
        'total',


    ];

 public function client()
    {
        return  $this->belongsTo(Client::class,);
    }
    public function clientemail()
    {
        return  $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'email');
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende... ¿Que es estirar datos? Ni siquiera terminaste la oración "...pero me esta estirando el id de la.".  Te sugiero que leas la documentación de laravel [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent) y [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships) y pruebes hacerlo, para luego consultar algo más específico que "estoy estirando datos de una tabla relacionado para guardar en una nueva tabla"

Comment: Con el formato actual es seguro te cierren la pregunta, sugiero leas [ask] y [mcve]

Comment: Al tener la relación creada, desde el apointment vas al cliente y cojes el id. `$appointment->client->email`